# ZipArchive does not properly compress files with MemoryStream

Tags: .net, compression, zip

I am using ZipArchive from .NET 4.5 and it's correctly working with `FileStream`:

```
public static byte[] CompressWithFiles(string dir)
{
    var archiveName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".zip");    
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(testsConsoleDir);
    using (var stream = new FileStream(archiveName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }
    }
    byte[] result = File.ReadAllBytes(archiveName);

    return result;
}
```

But if I am trying to compress files with `MemoryStream` it returns bytes array which can not be open being saved to disk:

```
public static byte[] CompressInMemory(string dir)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
    byte[] result = null;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);

            stream.Position = 0;
            result = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(result, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I compared arrays from first and second methods and found out that they are equal except the fact that first array have a rest bytes at the end which maked zip archive openable. How can I fix this issue in `CompressInMemory` method? I am trying to avoid data storing on the disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must "close" the zip BEFORE reading it:

```
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    foreach (var file in files)
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
}

stream.Position = 0;
result = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(result, 0, (int)stream.Length);        

// Note that you can replace the previous 3 rows
// from stream.Position = 0 onward) with:
//result = stream.ToArray();
```

But you must set the `ZipArchive` to leave the stream "non-disposed" (the final `true`) when it is closed.

In this way the zip is "flushed" to the stream. if you note you did it correctly in the `FileStream` example.

In general you should `stream.Flush()` **before** doing the `stream.Position = 0`, because the `stream` could have some unwritten internal buffers, but with `MemoryStream` this isn't necessary, because [MemoryStream.Flush()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Overrides the Stream.Flush method **so that no action is performed**.

Comment: I tried this code. But it throws an `ObjectDisposedException`. Adding `stream.Flush()` has no effect.

Comment: @KvanTTT Tested. Add a `true` as the last parameter of `new ZipArchive`. See explanation added.